# How to choose an element based on 'contains' using xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this particular XML that I am using to experiment with Xpath:

```
`<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "students.xsl"?>
<class>
   <student rollno = "393">
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno = "493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno = "593">
      <firstname>Jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>Singh</lastname>
      <nickname>Jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>`
```

What I would like to do is choose a first name in the tree, only if the marks are 85. E.g choose the first element. I want it to be dynamic and do not want to hardcode and choose the n'th element as I have tried.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath expression selects all `firstname` elements which are on the same level as a `marks` element with the value `85`:

```
//firstname[../marks='85']
```

A more generic version only checks for the presence of `85` in the value:

```
//firstname[contains(../marks,'85')]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. How can you extend this to make it even more dynamic, for example if the marks contains a string that says "this students marks are 85", and still match on '85'? Thanks again!

Comment: @SkSnat - You need to be precise in your requirements in that case. Will the text always be "this student marks are XX", or can it be other text? Could there be multiple numbers in it too? What happens if one record says "This student got 85 out of 100", but another says "Out of a possible 100, this student got 85"? Thanks!